# android kotlin: storing retrieved data from url to room database

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, local-storage, android-room

method i made:

```
    private fun saveToRoom(albums: Array<Data>) {

    doAsync {
        /*val currentDBPath = getDatabasePath("albums_database").absolutePath
        println("DBPath is " + currentDBPath)*/

        var items = ArrayList<ProductList_Data>()

        for (album in albums) {
            val item = ProductList_Data()
            item.name = album.name
            item.price = album.price
            items.add(item)

        }

        db?.productListDao()?.insert(items)

        /*val musicAlbums = db?.productListDao()?.getAll()
        activityUiThread {
            longToast("Data Got saved")
            refreshUIWith(musicAlbums!!)
        }*/
    }

}
```

this is data class names Data

```
data class Data(
val _links: Links?,
val attributes: List<Attribute>?,
val average_rating: String?,
val backordered: Boolean?,
val backorders: String?,
val backorders_allowed: Boolean?,
val button_text: String?,
val catalog_visibility: String?,
val categories: List<Category>?,
val cross_sell_ids: List<Any>?,
val custom_fields: CustomFields?,
val date_created: String?,
val date_created_gmt: String?,
val date_modified: String?,
val date_modified_gmt: String?,
val date_on_sale_from: Any?,
val date_on_sale_from_gmt: Any?,
val date_on_sale_to: Any?,
val date_on_sale_to_gmt: Any?,
val default_attributes: List<Any>?,
val description: String?,
val dimensions: Dimensions?,
val download_expiry: Int?,
val download_limit: Int?,
val downloadable: Boolean?,
val downloads: List<Any>?,
val external_url: String?,
val featured: Boolean?,
val grouped_products: List<Any>?,
val id: Int?,
val images: List<Image>?,
val manage_stock: Boolean?,
val menu_order: Int?,
val meta_data: List<MetaData>?,
val name: String?,
val on_sale: Boolean?,
val parent_id: Int?,
val permalink: String?,
val price: String?,
val price_html: String?,
val purchasable: Boolean?,
val purchase_note: String?,
val rating_count: Int?,
val regular_price: String?,
val related_ids: List<Int>?,
val reviews_allowed: Boolean?,
val sale_price: String?,
val shipping_class: String?,
val shipping_class_id: Int?,
val shipping_required: Boolean?,
val shipping_taxable: Boolean?,
val short_description: String?,
val sku: String?,
val slug: String?,
val sold_individually: Boolean?,
val status: String?,
val stock_quantity: Any?,
val stock_status: String?,
val tags: List<Any>?,
val tax_class: String?,
val tax_status: String?,
val total_sales: Int?,
val type: String?,
val upsell_ids: List<Any>?,
val variations: List<Int>?,
val virtual: Boolean?,
val weight: String?
```

)    i want to get only name and price to be stored in room database

entity class that i am using :

```
@Entity(tableName = "productlisttable")
data class ProductList_Data(
@PrimaryKey
val uid: Int = 0,

@ColumnInfo(name = "_name")
var name: String? = "",

@ColumnInfo(name = "_price")
var price: String? = ""
```

)

calling method in main activity and getting red underline error that no values passed for init and all that

```
        saveToRoom(Array<Data>))
```

i think the way i am calling the method is wrong or what

Answer (score 0):

Use this function to convert and save array in database

```
@TypeConverter
    fun fromStringList(stringList: List<String?>?): String? {
        if (stringList == null) return null
        val type = object : TypeToken<List<String?>?>() {}.type
        return Gson().toJson(stringList, type)
    }
```